# Why Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String, Number, Object, Boolean, got Array shows for the program below mention?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

Why  Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String, Number, Object, Boolean, got Array        shows for the program below mention?

html:

```
<model-select :options="usersAssignData"  v-model="userNameData" class="form-control col-sm-4" @keyup.native="getUser"  >
```

script:

```
 getUser(e) { 
       console.log("idd",this.selectedZone)
        var user = e.target.value;
        axios.get("/helpdesk/getUsers", {
        params: {
          q: user,
          account_id: this.selectedZone,
          searchOption: 'username'
        },
          headers: {
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.usersAssignData = response.data

        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is it `model-select` that is reporting the error or a child component? What is the format of `userNameData`? What about `usersAssignData`? If it is `model-select` that is reporting the error directly then it is probably a problem with the `v-model` value, so `userNameData`. If it's a child component then it could be a problem with `usersAssignData`. Is `model-select` a wrapper around a Vuetify component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **type** of the prop `usersAssignData` of your component is probably not an Array, and the axios call it seems to be returning an Array. Try doing what @DharaParmar said, setting the type of the prop as an array.

Answer (score 2):

### Try using the below code in file which you want to use your props value

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            usersAssignData: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => [],
            },
        },
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you imported your component to which you want to pass the prop?

Comment: I got the answer . I use the " for loop " instead of " options " in html

Answer (score -1):

hey this works for me:

```
data() {
  return {
    usersAssignData:Array/Object/String/Number,
  }
}
```

now usersAssignData can be Array or Object or String Or Number and your not gonna see that error anymore ;)

Comment: Maybe it works, but for sure this is a bad coding pattern.

Comment: Sometimes it just matters to work , Like when you have little time and a nonsensical employer, I hope that the person who gave me a negative score will one day be in this situation too :)

Comment: @ArianFm we've all been there, but the likely reason you're fixing a bug on a short timescale is because someone _else_ hacked a fix before you. There's an excellent chance that someone else will need to resolve what you may have done above. This is what we call "technical debt" and leaving someone else to pay debt in the future is what causes bosses to rush fixes. We've all been there, but it's our job as good engineers to break the cycle, not feed it :)