# vue warning: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "modalState". Expected Boolean, got Function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I ran into this warning, but I don't understand it. I already searched StackOverflow and there are a number of posts but they are all different and don't solve my problem. I read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59579104/why-invalid-prop-type-check-failed-for-prop-value-expected-string-number-o) which is generic and I think I already implemented the mentioned solution. The warning still shows in the console.
This is my component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <p>Vakken</p><input id="plusButton" type="button" value="+" @click = "openAddSubject">
    <table>
        <th>
            <tr>
                <td>Afkorting</td>
                <td>Beschrijving</td>
                <td>Geblokt</td>
                <td>Kleur</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </th>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="subject in subjects" :key = "subject.abbr">
                <td>{{subject.abbr}}</td>
                <td>{{subject.desc}}</td>
                <td>{{subject.blocked}}</td>
                <td>{{subject.color}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <add-subject :modal-state="addSubjectOpen" />
</div>

</template>

<script>
   import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
   import AddSubject from './AddSubject.vue'


   export default {
    components: { AddSubject },
    name: "Subjects",

data(){
    return{
        addSubjectOpen:Boolean
    }
},

mounted(){
    this.addSubjectOpen = false
},

methods: {
  openAddSubject(){
    this.addSubjectOpen = true
  }
},


}
</script>
```

When the button is clicked, the value of addSubjectOpen is set to true through the method openAddSubject. The prop modal-state of  is than set to true and the modal is shown.
The type of addSubjectopen is Boolean.

This is the code of AddSubject.Vue

```
 <template>
<div class="modal" :class="modalState?'is-active':''" >
<div class="modal-background"></div>
<div class="modal-card">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
    <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
    <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-card-body" id = "modal">
    <!-- Content ... -->
    Gewoon wat tekst
    </section>
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
    <button class="button is-success">Opslaan</button>
    <button class="button">Annuleren</button>
    </footer>
</div>
</div>    
</template>

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

    export default {
     name: 'AddSubject',

     props: {
        modalState:Boolean,
     },
}
</script>
```

Again the type of the prop modalState is definitely set to Boolean. So why is it passed as a function? By the way, the components work as expected, it is just the warning in the console that bothers me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
data() {
    return {
        addSubjectOpen: false // or true, depending on needs
    }
},
```